# Reading log files using logstash which rotates every day

Tags: linux, logging, inode, logrotate

I am reading a log file using file input plugin in logstash and sending this logs to elastic search. Log file is rotated at every 00:00. When I rotate log file, the file is zipped and moved to a different folder. New logs will be written to the same file from the beginning.
So my question is, if logstash is so slow to keep up with the amount of logs written to the file, there will be some lag, in that case if the file content is moved for rotation then will I lost the logs which lagged? What is the expected behavior? If the logs are lost while rotation, how can I fix that?